# Error when installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's my first attempt with Rails, and when I'm trying to install it I get the following answer.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>$ rvm use --default 2.2
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any kind of help, would be much appreciated :)

Comment: First thing would be to remove the `$` symbol. This is most often used as the unix prompt, to indicate that this is a command to be typed. The command would be `rvm use ...` - but then indeed you'll need something that works on Windows (see below).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to manage multiple versions of ruby on windows please use [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) which is an excellent tool by Gordon Thiesfeld. You can find it on GitHub. There are plans to include windows support in RVM 2.0 => https://www.bountysource.com/fundraisers/489-rvm-2-0.